# Using xslt get node value at X position

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, msxsl

How can I get using xslt, node value at X position, without using foreach

```
<items>
<item1>x</item1>
<item2>x</item2>
<item3>x</item3>
</items>
```

This is explained in programming sense:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Items/Item[2]"/>
```

==================================================

Just to little expand question, in the following xml:

```
<items>
    <about>xyz</about>
    <item1>
       <title>t1</title>
       <body>b1</body>
    </item1>
    <item2>
       <title>t2</title>
       <body>b2</body>
    </item2>
    <item3>
       <title>3</title>
       <body>3</body>
   </item3>
</items>
```

**How can I select second's item title.**

Comment: Good question, +1. Do note that most answers contain expressions that, depending on the XML document, can potentially select a `title` that isn'r a child of an `item`XYZ parent.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answer to expanded question. You can use the positional value if you select a node-set of the wanted elements:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(items//title)[2]"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="(items/*/title)[2]"/>
```

Note the usage of the parenthesis required to return wanted node-set before selecting by position.

---

You can use what you called "in programming sense". However you need `*` due to the unknown name of the children elements:

```
<xsl:value-of select="items/*[2]"/>
```

Note that nodes-sets in XSLT **are not** zero-based. In the way above you are selecting the second **item**, not the **third one**.

You really need `position()` when you want compare the current position with a number as in:

```
<xsl:value-of select="items/*[position()>2]"/>
```

to select all **item** with position grater than 2. Other case where `position()` is indespensible is when position value is a variable of type **string**:

```
<xsl:variable name="pos" select="'2'"/>
<xsl:value-of select="items/*[position()=$pos]"/>
```

Comment: I've answered the expanded question. Hope it helps.

Comment: This helped me a lot with a similar problem. Great, simple solution, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> Just to little expand question, in the following xml:
>
> ```
> <items> 
>     <about>xyz</about> 
>     <item1> 
>        <title>t1</title> 
>        <body>b1</body> 
>     </item1> 
>     <item2> 
>        <title>t2</title> 
>        <body>b2</body> 
>     </item2> 
>     <item3> 
>        <title>3</title> 
>        <body>3</body> 
>    </item3> 
> </items>
> ```
>
> **How can I select second's item title**.

**Use**:

```
/*/*[starts-with(name(), 'item')][2]/title
```

**This selects**: all `title` elements that are children of the second of all children-elements of the top element, whose names are starting with the string `"item"`.

**Do note that expressions such as**:

```
(items/*/title)[2]
```

or

```
(items//title)[2]
```

**are not correct in general**, because if in the XML document there are other elements such as (say) `"chapter"` that have `title` children, the above expressions could select an `chapter/title` element -- **but the task here is to select the second `title` in the document whose parent could only be an `item`XYZ** element.

Comment: +1 for more general solution. However, the expressions in my answer _are correct_ in the provided sample; they could obviously work wrong if the input document changes. This can happen to your provided expression also.

Comment: @empo: Thanks, and yes, while my solution is more general and robust than yours, there is always chance that even more radical changes could make *any* solution unsuitable. So, I usually care for variations that are *quite possible*, but *not extreme*.

Comment: I agree, but to say that the expressions I've used in my answer _are not correct_ it is not correct :). You can say that those expressions are less robust and may fail if the input document changes.

Comment: @empo: This is essentially what I am saying, if you read well. I agree with your argument, so I just edited and replaced "are not correct" with "are not correct in general" :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use position()

```
<xsl:value-of select="/items/*[position()=2]/text()"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with

```
<xsl:value-of select="items/child[position()=2]"/>
```